# Convert from 2 or 4 bytes to signed/unsigned short/int

Tags: java, int, byte, type-conversion

I have to convert bytes to signed/unsigned int or short.

The methods below are correct? Which is signed and which unsigned?

Byte order: LITTLE_ENDIAN

```
public static int convertTwoBytesToInt1(byte b1, byte b2) {
    return (int) ((b2 << 8) | (b1 & 0xFF));
}
```

VS.

```
public static int convertTwoBytesToInt2(byte b1, byte b2) {
    return (int) (( (b2 & 0xFF) << 8) | (b1 & 0xFF));
}
```

and

```
public static int  convertFourBytesToInt1(byte b1, byte b2, byte b3, byte b4){
    return (int) ((b4<<24)+(b3<<16)+(b2<<8)+b1);
}
```

VS.

```
public static int  convertFourBytesToInt2(byte b1, byte b2, byte b3, byte b4){
    return (int) (( (b4 & 0xFF) << 24) | ((b3 & 0xFF) << 16) | ((b2 & 0xFF) << 8) | (b1 & 0xFF));
}
```

I'm interested **only** in this conversion forms. Thanks!

Comment: I would use ByteBuffer as this can be much more efficient and you can just set `.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first method (`convertXXXToInt1()`) of each pair is signed, the second (`convertXXXToInt2()`) is unsigned.

However, Java `int` is always signed, so if the highest bit of `b4` is set, the result of `convertFourBytesToInt2()` will be negative, even though this is supposed to be the "unsigned" version.

Suppose a `byte` value, `b2` is -1, or 0xFF in hexadecimal. The `<<` operator will cause it to be "promoted" to an `int` type with a value of -1, or 0xFFFFFFFF. After the shift of 8 bits, it will be 0xFFFFFF00, and after a shift of 24 bytes, it will be 0xFF000000.

However, if you apply the bitwise `&` operator, the higher-order bits will be set to zero. This discards the sign information. Here are the first steps of the two cases, worked out in more detail.

Signed:

```
byte b2 = -1; // 0xFF
int i2 = b2; // 0xFFFFFFFF
int n = i2 << 8; // 0x0xFFFFFF00
```

Unsigned:

```
byte b2 = -1; // 0xFF
int i2 = b2 & 0xFF; // 0x000000FF
int n = i2 << 8; // 0x0000FF00
```

Comment: At convertFourBytesToInt1 b1 doesn't have &0xff...So if I don't put it makes no difference? Is still signed int?

Comment: @blackwolf Actually, it will make a difference, because you are combining bytes with the `+` operator. I didn't notice that before, because the others use the `|` operator, which is preferred for bit manipulation. The expression should be `(int)((b4<<24) | ((b3 & 0xFF)<<16) | ((b2 & 0xFF)<<8) | (b1 & 0xFF))`

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the 4-byte unsigned conversion, because it doesn't fit into an int. The routines below work correctly.

```
public class IntegerConversion
{
  public static int convertTwoBytesToInt1 (byte b1, byte b2)      // signed
  {
    return (b2 << 8) | (b1 & 0xFF);
  }

  public static int convertFourBytesToInt1 (byte b1, byte b2, byte b3, byte b4)
  {
    return (b4 << 24) | (b3 & 0xFF) << 16 | (b2 & 0xFF) << 8 | (b1 & 0xFF);
  }

  public static int convertTwoBytesToInt2 (byte b1, byte b2)      // unsigned
  {
    return (b2 & 0xFF) << 8 | (b1 & 0xFF);
  }

  public static long convertFourBytesToInt2 (byte b1, byte b2, byte b3, byte b4)
  {
    return (long) (b4 & 0xFF) << 24 | (b3 & 0xFF) << 16 | (b2 & 0xFF) << 8 | (b1 & 0xFF);
  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    byte b1 = (byte) 0xFF;
    byte b2 = (byte) 0xFF;
    byte b3 = (byte) 0xFF;
    byte b4 = (byte) 0xFF;

    System.out.printf ("%,14d%n", convertTwoBytesToInt1 (b1, b2));
    System.out.printf ("%,14d%n", convertTwoBytesToInt2 (b1, b2));

    System.out.printf ("%,14d%n", convertFourBytesToInt1 (b1, b2, b3, b4));
    System.out.printf ("%,14d%n", convertFourBytesToInt2 (b1, b2, b3, b4));
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the b1 & 0xFF for?

Comment: @ScottF - to prevent negative values.